# No Option to 'Extract' under 'Raster' tab

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, contour, gdal-contour

So I'm running an earlier version of QGIS (3.4.6, as it is supposed to be more stable I'm told) for a Field Geology course, however after installing it and adding DEM data I am unable to 'Extract>Contours' as the option is not there. Is there a tool I don't have active?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the 'Contour' algorithm via the processing toolbox under GDAL > Raster extraction.

[image]

You can search/ filter the list of processing algorithms by typing 'contour' into the search bar.

[image]